# Which is the best sampler from Jmeter for creating Websocket connection as that request contains Bearer token as well in request payload

Tags: websocket, https, jmeter

Our Application is live event based application which creates 2-3 web-socket connection and it is a web-based application which makes both HTTP calls and Web-socket calls.
I have created a script for Https calls as unfortunately Jmeter does not support web-socket recording so I trying to insert web-socket calls manually with the help of web-socket Sampler but not sure which will be the best sampler for same as my request has access token in it.
I tried with Web-socket request-response sampler I am getting 200 OK but their is no data response from server when I compare it with browser developer tool i could see some messages flowing..

Can anyone let me know if I am doing something wrong or missing anything? OR what can be done to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe [JMeter WebSocket Samplers by Peter Doornbosch](https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers/src/master/) is what you're looking for.

As per **Features** section:

> integrates with JMeter's Header Manager to set additional HTTP headers on WebScoket upgrade request

so you will be able to add [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager), configure it to send [Authorization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) header with the value of `Bearer`  followed by your token and the Sampler will pick it up.

With regards to which one to choose - it depends on the nature of your application and how does the communication with the backend looks like, check out your [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) to see whether requests/and responses are coming via a single connection or a new one is being established for each frame and so on.

More information: [JMeter WebSocket Samplers - A Practical Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-websocket-samplers)